# Horizontal Hierarchical Layout

Tags: cytoscape

Is it possible to get cytoscape to display a hierarchical layout similar to the screenshot?[desired layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr5cl.png)

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry.  I don't know of any Cytoscape layouts that support that visualization.